# Is it possible to buy a frameset from Trek that isn't listed separately?

Tags: frames, build, trek

I am thinking of buying a Trek CrossRip or 720 touring bike, but I want it with Ultegra Di2 and the bikes are only listed on the Trek website with lower-end components.  So I'd like to buy a frameset and build it up the way I want...but how?  I don't live in the US and the official Trek LBS I've been to is outrageously expensive for everything, so ideally I'd want to buy online.  The Trek 720 is a brand new model so finding a used one in the right size seems very unlikely.

Some brands list framesets on their websites separately, including Trek, but the particular frames I'd want aren't listed this way.

Comment: Why are you asking here? Go to a Trek store and ask them if they will sell you a frame. Or go online and ask Trek. Everything you get here is an opinion, not a fact.

Comment: @GaryE IMHO not *everything* here is an opinion. Even the opinions are, in fact, facts.

Comment: But seriously, some answers do cite facts.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, Trek will not sell you just the frame if they don't offer it in their product lineup. And a bike shop wouldn't either, given that they have to buy the whole bike anyway. It's just a massive headache to allow things like that for manufacturers. And many manufacturers generally aren't all too keen on letting people sell their bikes online (accessories are fine to some extent).

Moreover, why would you put Di2 on a crossrip? It's frame isn't designed for it (e.g. mounting the battery), and its quite low end compared to what people would run Di2 on (a Di2 groupset costs *more* than most of the crossrip models out there, as complete bikes!)

Comment: It depends on the shop and their rep from the manufacturer.  Some manufacturers are more than willing to sell frame onlys to shops individually if it will get a shop rat at least riding their frame.  Also, some reps have greater leeway with swapping warranty frames with sale bikes etc.  Long story short, you might be able to get it done at your LBS and it doesn't hurt to ask.

Comment: @Chris *It depends on the shop and their rep from the manufacturer*. This is more true with highend frames, where the customer always wants a specific gruppo. But in that case, the frame is, as Batman says, in the product catalog.

Comment: As for why put Di2 on a CrossRip, it's simply because I want electronic shifting on an aluminum frame usable for light touring.  If you have a better suggestion of a frame to use for that, please do tell me.  I strongly considered the Planet X London Road, which is sold as a frameset, but unfortunately that bike's smallest size is too large (I need something around 48cm).  Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Kona's Jake the Snake had Di2 routing last year (unsure if it has it this year). But most people looking for touring look for simple, bulletproof systems rather than add complex systems like Di2.

Comment: @Batman: that Jake the Snake looks fairly close to what I'm after, thanks.  I can't tell anything about Di2 routing on the 2016 webpage for it.  As for touring with Di2, well, yes, it's not mainstream but that's OK with me.  I'm not riding through India with this thing.

Answer (score 5):

Yes they will as I just did it. I contacted trek support and asked for the part number for the 2017 crossrip frame set. Then went to local bike shop and they purchased it for me. Now looking forward to the build